# Pig passing date in yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can I pass a date to a pig script in a simple yyyy-MM-dd format?

I am passing a date like below:

```
pig -f script.pig -param dt="2016-06-03"
```

Within the script, if I use:

```
ToDate($dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

It shows me the output as:

```
1969-12-31T18:00:02.007-06:00
```

I tried reading from the pig ToDate documentation but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Which pig version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `'`

```
ToDate('$dt','yyyy-MM-dd')
```

check this example from documentation about parameter substitution:

```
%declare DESC 'Joe\'s URL'
A = load 'data' as (name, desc, url);
B = FILTER A by desc eq '$DESC';
```